# Unity netcode camera glitching between two players, how to fix?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem in which why unity project in which i am trying to test multiplayer in is semi broken, the movement works fine but when I ParrelSync in 2 players, and move the camera of the second player, it stays as the camera for both the players.

The code for my camera movement is

```
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class FirstPersonLook : NetworkBehaviour
{

    public Camera myCam;

    [SerializeField]
    public Transform character;
    public float sensitivity = 2;
    public float smoothing = 1.5f;

    Vector2 velocity;
    Vector2 frameVelocity;

    void Start()
    {
        // Lock the mouse cursor to the game screen.
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;

        // Get smooth velocity.
        Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));
        Vector2 rawFrameVelocity = Vector2.Scale(mouseDelta, Vector2.one * sensitivity);
        frameVelocity = Vector2.Lerp(frameVelocity, rawFrameVelocity, 1 / smoothing);
        velocity += frameVelocity;
        velocity.y = Mathf.Clamp(velocity.y, -90, 90);

        // Rotate camera up-down and controller left-right from velocity.
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-velocity.y, Vector3.right);
        character.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(velocity.x, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

and I have it as a child of an network object prefab player, which is the player prefab for the network manager

I have tried many things such as changing where the Client Network Transform script is held among other smaller tweaks, all of which have failed in their entirety. If anybody could help, or ask for more resources to help with, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to disable to the other players' cameras.  Right now you have a camera active for each client.

Comment: how do i do that for each player, assuring the correct camera is enabled?

Comment: You could have the camera on the player start disabled, and when the player spawns, check if the player is local and if so enable the camera.